# validate already registred user (via email) on facebook registration plugin

Tags: jquery, facebook, validation, plugins

i am developing a high application who uses user ( with username), I can validate if the user name exist, using onvalidate event asynchronus, but I already have old-user in my system.

How can I check if the new one to register user is already registered in my app? I mean can I check the email and the facebook ID on the validate?

I tried using form.email but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to add a column to your database where you store your users to include a facebook user id column (type: BigInt).  Then you can take the user ID that Facebook passes back to you to store in your database.  Ensure you give one of your existing customers the ability to log into their existing account without going thru facebook, then have some code for linking one of your existing users to their facebook user.